# How can I tell gcc to warn (or fail) on switch/case statements without a break?

Tags: c++, gcc, switch-statement, gcc-warning

I have a complicated `switch` statement, and I forgot to put a `break` at the end of one of the `case`s.  This is quite legal, and as a result I had a fall-through to the next `case`.

Is there any way to have gcc warn (or even better, fail) if I neglect to put a `break` statement?

I realize that there are many valid use cases (and I use them often in my code), as exemplified in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155524/switch-statement-without-break), so obviously such a warning (or failure) would need a simple waiver so that I could easily say, "I do want to fall-through here."

Is there any way to tell gcc to do this?

Comment: Honestly, if that's what you want, I would say just don't use switch/case. The only advantage of switch/case that still remains is that it is easy to get fall through where you want it.

Comment: Hehehe, C# forces you to put the break statement and won't compile if you don't

Comment: Just curious, can we see the code? Maybe there's an even better solution that doesn't require a switch.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The other advantage is that it's easier on the eye and easier to add new cases.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I don't think corporate security would like that idea :-)

Comment: I'm going to try writing a checker for this using the ROSE framework: http://rosecompiler.org/

Comment: Now although `gcc` support for this feature is still a work in progress, [clang has -Wimplicit-fallthrough](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27965827/1708801)

Answer (score 6):

There's a discussion about such a feature (-Wswitch-break) at http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7652. But it doesn't seem to be implemented yet

Comment: Looks like it got in in gcc 7

Answer (score 4):

This check is available in [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/), a free static analyser for C and C++ code. The check is currently marked "experimental", so you will need to use the `--experimental` command line switch to turn it on.

This check warns against a nonempty case clause that falls through to the next case without a control flow statement such as `break`, `continue`, `return`, etc, *unless* there is a comment with wording such as `// fall through` immediately preceding the next `case`.

You can get an idea for the kinds of constructs this handles by having a look at the [`switchFallThroughCase` test cases](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/blob/master/test/testother.cpp#L1468) in the source code.

Comment: I can no longer find this kind of check in cppcheck-1.83 and am not able to enable it with --experimental

Answer (score 3):

GCC 7 has a warning enabled with `-Wextra` or `-Wimplicit-fallthrough(=[1-5])?`: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/10/wimplicit-fallthrough-in-gcc-7/

Answer (score 2):

I just went through gcc options, and there is none that will at least give you a notice.
There are -Wswitch, -Wswitch-default and -Wswitch-enum ( http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options ), but none of them will work for you.

my best bet would be to use 'else if' statements

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a regexp for grep/perl/emacs/etc to find all places where there's no `break` before `case`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, there is no such flag in gcc to do that. Switch case is used for the fall through more often so that is why it does not make sense to have such a flag in gcc.

Comment: I think it makes sense, it just doesn't need to default to on.  Seems like it may be appropriate for -Wextra or -pedantic.