# How to make gcc/clang warn about missing breaks in switch statements

Tags: gcc, coding-style, switch-statement, clang, gcc-warning

Is there any way to make `gcc` or `clang` warn about missing breaks in switch statements?

Specifically, I almost always want case statements to end with breaks, and it would be great it I could get the compiler to complain if I don't. Even better would be if it would look for either a break statement or a "// fall through" comment.

Is there a different solution people use to help themselves not screw this up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell gcc to warn (or fail) on switch/case statements without a break?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703358/how-can-i-tell-gcc-to-warn-or-fail-on-switch-case-statements-without-a-break)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With Clang trunk, use `-Wimplicit-fallthrough`. If you're using C++11, intentional fallthrough can be marked with a `[[clang::fallthrough]];` statement (see [the documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#clang__fallthrough) for this attribute for more information). The warning does not (yet) check for 'fall through' comments. This feature won't be in the upcoming 3.1 release of Clang, but it will (probably!) be in 3.2.

**Edit:** Clang's attribute is now part of C++17, under the name `[[fallthrough]];`.

Comment: I see you just checked this feature in http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=rev&revision=156086. Thanks! And thanks to Alexander Kornienko!

Comment: Alexander deserves all the credit here, all I did was to review it. :)

Comment: C++17 now has the [[fallthrough]] attribute.

Comment: gcc 7 will have -Wimplicit-fallthrough as well (already included in Fedora 26 prerelease). Interestingly, I cannot get clang 3.9.1 to report fallthrough, even though it accepts the flag.

Comment: @RichardSmith I see it now, thanks. So, clang does it only with C++ and only if the standard is specified. gcc does it even with C.

Comment: @proski Clang only warns on this for configurations where there is a way to suppress the warning. Otherwise this would be extremely annoying to people building with -Weverything.

Answer (score 4):

The warning `-Wimplicit-fallthrough` was implemented in GCC 7. (http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7652)

The default "level" for the option is 3. What this means is explained either here in GCC docs (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wimplicit-fallthrough) or in a blog by the feature implementer (https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/10/wimplicit-fallthrough-in-gcc-7).

Besides the magic comments to mark a fallthrough, in C23 there is also a [new `[[fallthrough]]` attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/attributes/fallthrough) with is compatible with the C++17 attribute. In versions prior to that, use either the magic comment, or the nonstandard (GCC/Clang specific) `__attribute__ ((fallthrough))`. Wrap this in a macro if you also need to support MSVC.

Here's one way how to do the compatible macro. Use your project's prefix in the macro name (instead of the `PN` I choose).

```
// fallthrough
#if defined __cplusplus && defined __has_cpp_attribute
    #if __has_cpp_attribute(fallthrough) && __cplusplus >= __has_cpp_attribute(fallthrough)
        #define PN_FALLTHROUGH [[fallthrough]]
    #endif
#elif defined __STDC_VERSION__ && defined __has_c_attribute
    #if __has_c_attribute(fallthrough) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= __has_c_attribute(fallthrough)
        #define PN_FALLTHROUGH [[fallthrough]]
    #endif
#endif
#if !defined PN_FALLTHROUGH && defined __has_attribute
    #if __has_attribute(__fallthrough__)
        #define PN_FALLTHROUGH __attribute__((__fallthrough__))
    #endif
#endif
#if !defined PN_FALLTHROUGH
    #define PN_FALLTHROUGH (void)0
#endif
```

(from https://github.com/apache/qpid-proton/blob/001195c05a5fa1ec3d3b14a4963b82556450819f/c/include/proton/annotations.h#L93-L110)

Answer (score 2):

You asked that it would be great if it will look for either a break statement or a "// fall through" comment.

Remember Henry Spencer's first of the **[Ten Commandments for C programmers](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ten-commandments.html)**?

*1. Thou shalt run lint frequently*

It looks like what you need is PC-Lint / flexelint. Here is warning 616:

> **616 control flows into case/default** -- It is possible for flow of
>   control to fall into a case statement or a default statement from
>   above. Was this deliberate or did the programmer forget to insert a
>   break statement? If this was deliberate then place a comment
>   immediately before the statement that was flagged as in:

```
case 'a': a = 0;
   /* fall through */
case 'b': a++;
```