# How do I find a case without a break; in a switch-statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I found a bug in my code. I simply forgot a `break;` before starting a new case of a switch statement. So, the code looked like

```
switch (nCounter)
{
case 1:
    *dReturnValue = 1.;
    // here should have been a break;
case 2:
    *dReturnValue = 2.;
    break;
default:
    *dReturnValue = 3.;
    break;
}
```

How can I use regex to find two cases (or `case` ... `default:`) without a `break;` in between?

Thanks

Philipp

Comment: Any decent compiler would warn you about that.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809154/how-to-make-gcc-clang-warn-about-missing-breaks-in-switch-statements

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ And in many cases this is feature and expected behavior, not a bug.

Comment: @i486 That's why you usually comment that with `// fall through` to make the intend explicit.

Comment: Search compiler output for warnings with the world "break". Almost all modern compilers prints such warning

Comment: @i486 that's why it's a warning and not an error. Also C++17 adds the `[[fallthrough]]` attribute for that case

Comment: I know, it can be a feature but in my case it wasn't. I use Visual Studio Professional 2013 and don't get any warnings. Why? I'm not sure, if I understand the link @stijn sent. Is "With Clang trunk, use `-Wimplicit-fallthrough`" the key? What does it mean?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ: It was just a minimal example.

Comment: now I get it :)

Comment: Your question is about regex I think, not really c++ specific?

Comment: You could use the clang-query tool to search for that.

Comment: Were you able to work out the regex?

Answer (score 0):

The most backwards compatible answer to your question is something like this:

```
case(\n|[^bc]|c[^a]|ca[^s]|cas[^e]|b[^r]|br[^e]|bre[^a]|brea[^k])*case
```

[link](http://regexr.com/3g2v6) :)

## Explaination:

1. Look for and consume the word `case`.
2. Look and consume any letters other than `b`.
3. You may also consume any `b` that is not followed by an `r`.
4. Same goes `br` not followed by `e` and so forth up to `break` without `k`.
5. If followed by the word case, consume any substring of `brea` that starts from the first character.

## comments:

This could be extended to include break followed by anything other than white space and a semicolon but I only wanted to give you the general idea (meaning this will fail on `case breakthrough case` for instance). Also, the word case should be followed by a colon.

Comment: Thanks zehelvion. There are search results, when I remove the second "case". Of course, the search results are not what I was looking for but the problem is, that my Visual Studio freezes, when there is something after "?)". Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, that was not quite correct. VS freezes with the second "case" only if there is no search result.

Comment: Did you test your regex when there is no result? I still cannot use it because my VS freezes.

Comment: @Flippowitsch I removed the ?? because you shouldn't need them for your use case. This: `case(\n|[^bc]|c[^a]|ca[^s]|cas[^e]|b[^r]|br[^e]|bre[^a]|brea[^k])*case` seems to work fine in VS for me. Make sure you don't have `break` in a comment cause it will 'think' it's a real break. :)

Comment: And it seems like it doesn't freeze now. Let me know if it's still freezing.

Comment: Oh, and send a bug report to VS if you can. It shouldn't freeze because of a regexp even it's horribly written. ;)

Comment: It took me hours to find the problem but finally I found it. Try [this](http://regexr.com/3g3qc) in VS. It will work. But add some lines `A = 0;` and (important!) the blank line. You will see, that the search takes longer and longer with every `A = 0;` and blank line you add. So actually VS did not freeze but the search takes really long. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. It's possible to build the same logic as switch/case with a little templatery.

Note the use of lambdas to execute the code in each case. This ensures that only one code path is taken.

This is a minimal example. Note that in an optimised build, this is likely to be no less efficient than a switch/case.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct Switcher
{
  Switcher(T const& value) : value_(value) {}

  template<class F>
  auto On(T const& candidate, F&& f) -> Switcher&
  {
    if (not satisfied_ and candidate == value_)
    {
      satisfied_ = true;
      f();
    }

    return *this;
  }

  template<class F>
  auto Otherwise(F&& f)
  {
    if (not satisfied_) {
      satisfied_ = true;
      f();
    }
  }

private:
  T const& value_;
  bool satisfied_ = false;
};

template<class T> auto Switch(T const& value)
{
  return Switcher<T>(value);
}

int main(int argc)
{
  Switch(argc)
  .On(1, []{ std::cout << "one arg\n"; })
  .On(2, []{ std::cout << "two args\n"; })
  .Otherwise([]{ std::cout << "more args\n"; });
}
```