# Confusion in gcc switch case assembly

Tags: c

My Prog.c contains a simple switch case as follows:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 1:
        p=2;
        break;
    case 2:
        p=3;
        break;
    case 3:
        p=4;
        break;
    case 4:
        p=5;
        break;
    case 5:
        p=6;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

I compiled this program with

```
gcc -g -v prog.c
```

and created objdump with

```
objdump -S -l a.out>dump_file
```

For the switch case statement, I have found that one indirect branch has been created (`jmp *%eax`).

But if I remove any one of the case statement, no indirect branch is created.

**gcc version**: `5.4.0`

I could not understand why this is happening?

Comment: It might be useful to show us the output. Currently you could simply do `if (x>=1 && x<=5) p=x+1;` or jump to an address calculated from `x`. This does not work if you have a gap in the cases list.

Comment: Compiler optimization decide to use indirect jumps than multiple comparisons.

Comment: maybe similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/11668346/7508077

Answer (score 0):

This is happen because of [Branch Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table). to avoid it compile with

`gcc -g -v -fno-jump-tables SO.c`

If you compile with jump tables [a feature in gcc compiler] size of `dump_file` is: 9,965 bytes

But without it size is: 11,493 bytes.

Jump tables helps to reduce object code size by optimize and relocate some jump instructions.