# Switch case's jump table position within code on ARM

Tags: c, arm, reverse-engineering, compiler-optimization, jump-table

In C/C++ a switch statement can be lowered by the compiler to [a jump table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837656/jump-table-switch-case-question). I noticed a difference of placement of the jump table between ARM and x86.

### x86

For x86 (And x86_64) the jump table is often placed **outside** of the function (e.g. .rodata)

```
  4005e0:       48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
  4005e4:       48 8b 0c c5 b0 0c 40    mov    0x400cb0(,%rax,8),%rcx
  4005eb:       00 
  4005ec:       ff e1                   jmpq   *%rcx
  4005ee:       8b 45 e8                mov    -0x18(%rbp),%eax
  4005f1:       83 e8 66                sub    $0x66,%eax
```

### ARM

For ARM the jump table is **interleaved** with function's code.

```
 15c:   e28f2004        add     r2, pc, #4
 160:   e7911002        ldr     r1, [r1, r2]
 164:   e1a0f001        mov     pc, r1
 168:   000001a4        .word   0x000001a4
 16c:   000001b4        .word   0x000001b4
 170:   000001e4        .word   0x000001e4
 174:   00000214        .word   0x00000214
 178:   00000214        .word   0x00000214
 17c:   00000214        .word   0x00000214
 180:   00000214        .word   0x00000214
 184:   00000214        .word   0x00000214
 188:   000001c4        .word   0x000001c4
 18c:   000001f4        .word   0x000001f4
```

The above code was generated with `clang 3.5 -target arm-none-eabi -march=armv7`, but similar code is generated with `gcc`.

### MIPS

For completeness, here's the code for a switch statement on MIPS. The jump table is placed in the `.rodata` section.

```
 4002b8:    2c85000b    sltiu   a1,a0,11       
 4002bc:    afc40018    sw  a0,24(s8)       //local var that we switch on 
 4002c0:    10a00021    beqz    a1,400348 <main0+0xb4> // default case
 4002c4:    00000000    nop
 4002c8:    8fc10018    lw  at,24(s8)      //the var that we switch on is in at
 4002cc:    00011080    sll v0,at,0x2      // v0 = at<<2
 4002d0:    3c030040    lui v1,0x40        // v1 = 0x40<<16
 4002d4:    00431021    addu    v0,v0,v1   // v0 = (at<<2) + v1 
 4002d8:    8c421848    lw  v0,6216(v0)    // v0 = *((at<<2)+0x401848)
 4002dc:    00400008    jr  v0             // jump
 4002e0:    00000000    nop
```

The address of the jumptable (`0x00401848`) is in `.rodata`.

```
 $ readelf -e /tmp/muti-sw.mips.o  | grep .rodata
 [ 7] .rodata           PROGBITS        00401848 001848 00069a 00   A  0   0  4
```

The above code was generated with clang 3.9.

### Question

Why on ARM architecture the jump table is often interleaved with function's code and on x86 not?

[This answer implies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35846099/26730) that the way the cache is working on ARM has to do with it. Are there any other reasons?

Comment: IIRC, there are some differences in the ranges of some addressing modes between ARM and x86 that could explain this.

Comment: I bet the x86 and ARM parts of GCC are written by different people...

Comment: Yes, there are some differences. On ARM, you can use an immediate offset of max 4KB to address memory.

Comment: There are ARMs and there are ARMs. The answer you link to was explicitly talking about extreme-low-power-tiny-microcontrollers executing directly from flash. It would probably be useful to state in the question which instruction set and architecture profile you are building for. The compiler output for bare-metal T32 on a microcontroller has little bearing on codegen for A32 under Linux on an applications processor.

Comment: x86[-64] has variable-length instructions. In particular, it is possible to load a full-sized register *in a single instruction*. ARM, in contrast, only has 16- and 32-bit instructions, which simply cannot hold a full register immediate. Therefore, ARM tends to use small PC-relative offsets to load constants from literal-pools embedded in the text-section, while x86 embeds the constant in the immediate of an instruction (which naturally ends up in the text-section as well).

Comment: @EOF That is true in some contexts.  However, here both need to use a table to get some information about the case code size/offset.  There is no way the x86 can embed this information in a single instruction.  I guess here the `PC` comes loaded for free.  If you had to load a base table address on the ARM then your comment would apply.

Comment: @artlessnoise: The point I was trying to make is that on ARM, putting literal pools into the text-section to be accessed via an offset from PC is common and "idiomatic". On x86, there is no need to put such a table into the text-section, because you can encode an arbitrary address (with arbitrary relocations at load-time) in a single instruction.

Comment: I think the 4KB maximum reach is the reason. Functions can easily be longer than 4KB, so ARM is forced to put the jump table inside the function. x64 has a 2GB reach, which lets you put the jump table outside the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainly this has to do with RISC vs CISC philosophy.  On the ARM the PC is almost a general purpose register.  You can see that with `add r2, pc, #4`; this puts the address of the table in `r2`.  Since the table is loaded via the PC, it needs to go with the code.  A simpler switch is possible,

```
     ldr     r1, [r1, pc]  ; get table data via 'pc'
     add     pc, r1        ; do switch
table: 
     .word offset_first_case ; ... etc.
```

The above is completely `PC` relative.  It looks like your code might need a relocation.  If the case code is highly symmetric, a table might not even be needed just `pc += case * case_code_size`.

Some ARM CPUs support instructions like `xlat` and a switch/case implementation may depend on the compiler, target ARM/x86 CPU, the data type and the density of the cases.  For instance, the table might contain 'case,case_offset' and be sorted so a binary search is performed in the 'sparse case' case.

---

Note: The ARM `pc` is two instructions (eight bytes) ahead due to the original ARM pipeline size.  ARM maintains this offset when using the `PC` in order to stay compatible.

Comment: I would agree with [unixsmurf](http://stackoverflow.com/users/563188/unixsmurf), that caching issues depend on the ARM CPU (unified or separate code/data for instance).

Comment: I agree with @artless, the fact that ``PC`` is almost a general purpose register seems to have a big role. I also tested on MIPS, and the jump table is placed in ``.rodata`` section. On MIPS, one does not have *easy* access to ``PC``.